# Convert nested json file to Dataframe in R

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I have json file as given below. I want to convert it into dataframe.

```
json_file-> [{'a': "abc", "date": "20190506", "my_col":{"weather":10, "ice": 12}},
             {'a': "xyz", "date": "20190507", "my_col":{"summer":18, "hot": 14}}]
```

Data frame should look like below:

```
 a  date      mycol
abc 20190506 "weather":10, "ice": 12
xyz 20190507 "summer":18, "hot": 14
```

Attempt:

```
json_file <- fromJSON(json_file)

json_file <- lapply(json_file, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
})
```

Comment: what structure is `mycol` in your expected output? is it a list of a string of JSON?

Comment: It is a dictionary.

Comment: a "dictionary" is not really a *thing* in R.

Comment: Ok. I am writing code first time in R. Consider it list of strings.

Comment: Feel like this is pandas ...

Comment: Yeah. This is pandas. But in R I want to convert this json file into dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with `rjson` `fromJSON`

```
library(rjson)
l='[{"a": "abc", "date": "20190506", "my_col":{"weather":10, "ice": 12}},{"a": "xyz", "date": "20190507", "my_col":{"summer":18, "hot": 14}}]' 
l = fromJSON(l)
do.call(rbind, l)
     a     date       my_col
[1,] "abc" "20190506" List,2
[2,] "xyz" "20190507" List,2
```

Comment: What's this List?

Comment: @user15051990 convert to data.frame you will see , data.frame(do.call(rbind, l))

Comment: I am getting 10, 12. Is it not possible to get ["weather":10, "ice": 12] in column my_col?

Comment: @user15051990 that is just display , you can print out df$my_col, to see :-)